# Jquery based image mosaic wall layouts

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, layout, css-position

I'm looking to recreate the layout that's present at this site:

http://prettytasty.tumblr.com/archive/

The only way to accomplish this is using absolute positioning, however it appears that they're using javascript to dynamically position each image entry on the page. Is there a jquery plugin or example that accomplishes this or something similar?

I realize javascript is the last thing you want to have to depend on for layout, but I'm just curious and would like to see how it is accomplished.

Answer (score 14):

The effect you see on that particular page is actually created with prototype.js, but for jQuery you're probably looking for the [jQuery Masonry Plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: That's absolutely great and exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks for the suggestion!