# Javascript Toolkit for Draggable Mosaics?

Tags: javascript, datagrid, draggable

There's a style of web pages that's often seen in "status panel" applications.  Geckoboard is a very nice example - http://www.geckoboard.com/ - and Windows 8 appears to be similar in style (but perhaps not functionality).

Is there a Javascript toolkit that is supports such things?  In particular, it would allow items to be dragged around in the grid and support deletion/addition of panels.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't want to roll it all yourself, so jQuery is probably useful here. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198095/jquery-based-image-mosaic-wall-layouts

Comment: Not sure but probably [Ext JS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) has it.

Comment: Which, y'know, cites [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: that looks cool but doesn't seem to be draggable? if that's the best there is i'll go with that.  if you post an answer and nothing better comes up i'll hand out points.  and what do points mean?  eh i guess you need to be english and over 30 to get that.  never mind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Masonry was the best answer I got (see Jared's comment).

Answering this myself so I can mark the question as answered.  Aksed Jared long ago to post an answer himself (see comments).